# get error of size.isFinite when set top, bottom, left and right for positioned in stack

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, flutter-positioned, flutter-stacked

I have 3 positioned as children of Stack inside of ListView.builder also set top and right for all 4 positioned when run, got this error

```
size.isFinite
```

if used in the demo the stack and inside of positioned work well. how to solve.

here i have one list

```
  List<Widget> movableTextWidgets = [];
```

and one stack image

```
Stack(
              children: [
                Hero(
                  tag: "${widget.index}",
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 5 / 7, // Set your desired aspect ratio
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          boxShadow: const [
                            BoxShadow(
                              blurRadius: 4,
                            ),
                          ],
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: AssetImage("images/${widget.index}.png"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ...movableTextWidgets,
              ],
            )
```

if when i have click on the floation action button its called the one method and this method called MovableTextBox.

```
void _addMovableTextBox() {
    setState(() {
      movableTextWidgets.add(MovableTextBox());
    });
  }
```

when this class call the show error in return stack.

```
class MovableTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MovableTextBoxState createState() => _MovableTextBoxState();
}

const ballDiameter = 15.0;

class _MovableTextBoxState extends State<MovableTextBox> {
  double width = 200.0;
  double height = 80.0;
  double top = 100;
  double left = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
      top: top,
      left: left,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          setState(() {
            top += details.delta.dy;
            left += details.delta.dx;
          });
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: width,
              height: height,
            ),
            // Top left corner
            Positioned(
                  top: -ballDiameter / 2,
                  left: -ballDiameter / 2,
                  child: ManipulatingBall(
                    onDrag: (dx, dy) {
                      setState(() {
                        width -= dx;
                        height -= dy;
                        top += dy;
                        left += dx;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
            // Top right corner
            // Bottom left corner
            // Bottom right corner
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
    ]
    );
  }
}

class ManipulatingBall extends StatefulWidget {
  ManipulatingBall({Key? key, required this.onDrag}) : super(key: key);

  final Function onDrag;

  @override
  _ManipulatingBallState createState() => _ManipulatingBallState();
}

class _ManipulatingBallState extends State<ManipulatingBall> {
  late double initX;
  late double initY;

  _handleDrag(details) {
    setState(() {
      initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
      initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
    });
  }

  _handleUpdate(details) {
    var dx = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
    var dy = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;
    initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
    initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
    widget.onDrag(dx, dy);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: _handleDrag,
      onPanUpdate: _handleUpdate,
      child: Container(
        width: ballDiameter,
        height: ballDiameter,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

what my mistake in this code.

Comment: Can you give us full runnable code with a main method?
What do you mean used in demo?

Comment: This is also same as a demo code.

i have to make resizable container for add text on the image. in the demo code i have make resizable container ( i have post code). when i have add this code in my real app and run the code the resizable container not show and show error this:

Failed assertion: line 600 pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.

i have one stack image and this image i have to put text using of stack container.

Comment: I wanted to ask for code wiht a main method to be able to reproduce your problem.
If I add your code to a simple material design I get this when I run it https://imgur.com/a/ZXyG5IW
what do you mean add it to real app? How can I reproduce resizing?

Comment: i have edit code and given more information.

Comment: Where does ```${widget.index}``` come from in the hero tag? 
Could you please try to share a reproducable example? It's hard to use the first stack on it's own for me.
Otherwise, I read your opening line again and it's totally possible that if you only have 3 Positioned widgets on a Stack, the stack cannot find it's height. You need to include at least one height value for each stack so it knows how it should be drawn.
Make sure that all your stacks know how much their height is.

Comment: check this question for the full code from main method to end of code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741066/get-error-of-size-isfinite-when-set-positioned-for-container-in-stack-flutter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77844040/how-to-rotate-container-using-rotation-icon-in-flutter?noredirect=1#comment137234464_77844040