# how to rotate container using rotation icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-container

In this code i have to rotate text container. but the container rotate only one direction and than another not rotate full 360 degree.

the container move the 360 degree and smooth not more speed to rotation.

In this code i have to rotate text container. but the container rotate only one direction and than another not rotate full 360 degree.

the container move the 360 degree and smooth not more speed to rotation.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Resizable Rotatable Text Box'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyResizableTextBox(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyResizableTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyResizableTextBoxState createState() => _MyResizableTextBoxState();
}

class _MyResizableTextBoxState extends State<MyResizableTextBox> {
  double boxWidth = 200.0;
  double boxHeight = 100.0;
  double rotationAngle = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
            setState(() {
              boxWidth = 200.0 * details.scale;
              boxHeight = 100.0 * details.scale;
            });
          },
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: rotationAngle,
            child: Container(
              width: boxWidth,
              height: boxHeight,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Resizable Text Box',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            setState(() {
              rotationAngle += details.delta.dx /180;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.rotate_left,
            size: 36.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

what wrong in this code.

Comment: 1) The code actually works, but the way it's detecting gesture is just simply swipe right & swipe left on the button. If you swipe left it goes clockwise, if you swipe left it goes counter-clockwise. 2) To increase the rotation speed, in this code: `details.delta.dx /180` decrease that 180 to a lower number

Comment: when drag icon and move any direction container move this direction not using of swap icon again and again. if i have drag any direction container also rotate those direction.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean that's the **intended** behavior or that's the behavior that you're **getting**?